# unable to run xamarin in vs2017

Tags: android, xamarin

i am using xamarin in vs2017rc.I am trying to build an android app but everytime i am getting 
**Android application is debugging.
Couldn't connect to logcat, GetProcessId returned: 0**
output.
Anyone have any idea about it ?

Comment: *Anyone have any idea about it ?* I know .... RC is causing this

Comment: Is `adb` working on your machine? Can you rung `adb devices` command?

Comment: adb is working on my machine still same issue. i am working in windows 8

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old but I post here for anyone else who might have the same problem.

My problem was the new Android 8 and that Xamarin still (to date) can't debug on it. This will be fixed by replacing yet not released Android tools.

To do this download [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5k5ubvnixkfgdg/androitools-oreo.zip?dl=0) and replace the files on each of these locations:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin.VisualStudio

More info on this [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56740#c20).